# Cordova File-Transfer Not Hitting Server Endpoint

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a file using FT (cordova file-transfer) to send a file up to my express app.
The problem is, express doesn't get a request.  There was a point where it worked, but it stopped working and I'm trying to figure out why.

My code looks like this.

First I take a picture with cordova lib, this works.

```
    $scope.takePicture = function(){
          Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
            $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
            upload(imageURI)
          }, function(err) {
            console.err(err);
          }, {
            quality: 25,
            targetWidth: 320,
            targetHeight: 320,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
          });
    };
```

The upload function though, does not get a request up to the express server.

```
upload = function (imageURI) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey = "photo";
    options.fileName = 'filename'; // We will use the name auto-generated by Node at the server side.
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.httpMethod = 'put';
    options.params = { // Whatever you populate options.params with, will be available in req.body at the server-side.
        "description": "Uploaded from my phone"
    };

    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI(RESOURCES.PRODUCTION_DOMAIN + '/api/boats/' + $scope.boat._id),
        function (e) {
            console.log('File Transfer Completed', e)
        },
        function (e) {
            alert("Upload failed", e);
        }, options);
}
```

I don't see a request come into my server, and I see the console.log that fails.

Why is this?

My Server has the following access control methods

```
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
```

and I have

```
    <access origin="*"/>
```

In my config.xml for my app.

**Why do the requests do not get through!?**

**Edit**

After getting the app to run in x-code (downloaded the new version...)
I see the error is as follows.

```
2015-10-26 05:00:54.955 Fish App[358:68325] File Transfer Finished with response code 404
2015-10-26 05:00:54.956 Fish App[358:68325] FileTransferError {
    body = "";
    code = 3;
    "http_status" = 404;
    source = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/598EAE4A-F0E4-4A3B-A4A4-0DB657981122/tmp/cdv_photo_010.jpg";
    target = "http://example.com/api/boats/";
}
```

Also important to note I had to configure my nginx settings to allow larger than 1M file sizes, only THEN did I get the above error.  Why is it a 404?  The target is correct.

I have the following in my plist to allow all connections...

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Edit2:

I have added a CSP policy in my `index.html`  This seems to be the most insecure way to do it, which I would think would allow me to get the upload through!

```
<!-- This policy allows everything (eg CSS, AJAX, object, frame, media, etc) except that 
* CSS only from the same origin and inline styles,
* scripts only from the same origin and inline styles, and eval()
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src '*' script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE 2016-04-11:** Google will soon require new and updated Apps that use Cordova/Phonegap be at least 4.1.1 *Details:* [Android pre-4.1.1 to be blocked](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/android-block-pre-4.1.1.md)

You need to add the *white-list, the plugin, and CSP*. ***OR*** SET the version to your compiler.

### The fix to many common *white-list* problems

The alternative to the *white-list* is this quick fix – but know that this *quick fix* removes all needs for `white-list`. This creates a [security issue](http://www.androidauthority.com/google-webview-security-582363/) which you may not want to by pass.

<s>**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml` for **PHONEGAP BUILD ONLY**

`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`</s>

This method will not be available after May, 2016.

**THE LONG ANSWER IS** as such:

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 *Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler*
- #7 *Not setting "version" for you plugins*
- #10 *Not adding the new "white-list" and "white-list plugin" parameters in config.xml.*

For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all:
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
> http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

For #10

> This relatively * NEW * requirement means – to access ANY website or resources on the web, you MUST use the whitelist and the whitelist plugin. This requirement goes into affect, if you are using cordova-android@4.0.0 or better; including cli-5.1.1 and cli-5.2.0. If however, your version is before 4.0.0, let's say 3.5.0 or 3.7.0, then you will *not* have to add the *white-list* requirement.
>
> To be clear, the "whitelist" has been around for a bit, but the plugin and requirement is very new. As you would expect, when the "whitelist" was added, the defacto open-access feature was deprecated. Or said another way, the defacto open-access feature was planned and scheduled to be eliminated. This change marks a step in removal of the open-access feature.
>
> In addition, the Content Security Policy (CSP) has caught numerous developers - because it was soooo poorly publicized. **Depending on your use and the version of Phonegap you are using, the CSP needs to go in every single HTML page you used, just like you have to wait for 'deviceready'. However, there are cases where it is not needed at all. The documentation is confusing for some, please read it carefully.** The documentation is buried in the bottom of many of the latest documentation pages.
>
> Lastly, Raymond Camden in his blog points to a [LARGE change in policy starting with Cordova 5](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/05/25/important-information-about-cordova-5)

**Related Links**

> Phonegap Build Forum: [Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb) and now required Whitelist
>
> - [Cordova Whitelist Guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
> - [Phonegap Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)
> - [Phonegap Build Whitelist Guide](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html#Access%20Elements)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I am using ionic so I can expect the quick solution not to work, correct?  Secondly, is the white-list just for file uploads using the cordova-file transfer?

Comment: You can make the change on Ionic. The `white-list` is for ALL access to the internet. Please read [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) The answers to both those questions is there. And more answers.

Comment: I've read the post and there are some good tips in there.  Unfortunately, I believe I am whitelisting way more than I should be (ie everything). I've updated my post.  I'm now getting a 404 but the target specified is correct...

Comment: You have not stated (I should have asked), are you using iOS9? if so, you need to add `gap:` to your CSP definition in the page.

Comment: hey thanks for stickin with me, see the update edit:2 . Still getting the same error but I added a gap tag.

Comment: I have to confess, I'm writing a blog post right now, and this stuff is confusing. TRY this for your CSP `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`  Notice the `gap:` in the middle of it all? This may not fix it, but that's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Here is a link to my [RAW NOTES](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-system.md) on `white-list`

Comment: Had to add a script-src to that, but it's still not working I think it might be more minor than this.  I'm having trouble diagnosing the problem of the 404.  The endpoint exists. The file path is there.  Is there something I can look for in console logs to figure out what's actually going on?

Comment: I don't know of a way to get deeper into debuggin this. I think it is time to get more help. Is your code publicly available? We'll start with the `Phonegap Build` team, but they may send us to the Cordova team.